# Reading/Writing the raw data of the MIFARE DESFire EV2 cards connected from ACR1252U

Tags: nfc, mifare, pcsc, pyscard, acr1252

I am trying to read and write the raw binary to the MIFARE DESFire EV2 card but I am having a hard time understanding the correct APDU commands. I have some small binary data that I want to move physically through NFC cards, for this I want to be able to read and write to it.
I tired to follow the [ACR1252U API doc](https://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/6402/API-ACR1252U-1.17.pdf) and I followed these commands in sequence as described in the pdf.

```
'Start Transparent Session': "FF C2 00 00 02 81 00",
'Turn Antenna Field On': "FF C2 00 00 02 84 00",
'ISO 14443-4A Active': "FF C2 00 02 04 8F 02 00 04",
'Set the PCB to 0Ah and enable the CRC, parity and protocol prologue in the transmit data': "FF C2 00 01 0A 90 02 00 00 FF 6E 03 07 01 0A"
```

These ran fine with ok stauts (`90 00`) and after that I tried to authenticate and read the binary block with these commands in sequence.

```
'Load auth key into the reader': "FF 82 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF",
'Authentication for MIFARE Classic': "FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 04 60 00",
'Read 16 bytes starting from the binary block 80h':"FF B0 00 04 10"
```

But these commands fail with error `63 00` and sometimes after this error, the reader stops detecting the card until I replug the reader which seems very weird to me.

What am I doing wrong? I am completely new to NFCs and smart cards stuff. I have come to know that I can communicate with the card using APDU commands and have figured out a way to send those commands using pcsc (python pyscard) but I have very little knowledge of them and documentation are also hard to find. Can you please help with a step by step way to get a data from the card explaining what each APDU is doing or maybe some article or documentation which I can follow.

Also, I have seen docs talking about selecting file/application and AID in MIFARE DESFire EV2 and the ACR1252U API doc (mentioned above) does't talk about this. I don't know what it is, can you please explain about that? [MIFARE DESFire EV2 docs](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MF3DX2_MF3DHX2_SDS.pdf) shows the commands available but how to send that command to the card using ACR1252U?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is not a real "answer" to your question but tries to help you. As the documentation about Mifare DESFire EVx tag are available under a "Non Disclosure Agreement" (NDA) there is indeed not much documentation about these tags.

Fortunately there is "subtype" available - the **Mifare DESFire light** tag and the documentation is public available.

I recommend to read these documents:

datasheet: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MF2DLHX0.pdf

A fine "features and hints" document with "step by step" examples: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN12343.pdf

Additionally another tag has a very similar command system - the NTAG 424 DNA tag, for this tag the datasheet and "features and hints" application note is available as well - good luck.

B.t.w.: your question is off-topic here on Stackoverfl

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer. And, sorry for posting the off-topic question. Should I delete it or leave it like this now that I have already done the mistake?

Comment: Also, DESFire light datasheet provides the application id in it, so even if I know the commands from DESFire light datasheet, I can't know the default AIDs of EV2 card without its datasheet?

Comment: The DESFire Light comes with a "pre-installed" application, but the DESFire EVx is "empty". The usual steps to work with a DESFire EVx are 1) authenticate, 2) create an application, 3) create a file (e.g. a standard file), 4) authenticate with a "write" key, 5) write the data, 6) authenticate with a "read" key, 7) read the data from the file. And no, you won't need to delete the OT post :-)